# Continuation-passing style causes "Maximum call stack size exceeded " error

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I was trying to solve "fibonacci" sequence using "Continuation-passing style" in typescript which is a very easy example, but just to try

```
const cpsFib = (n: number, f: (t: number) => void) => {
  if(n === 0 || n === 1) f(1);
  else {
    cpsFib(n - 1, (t0) => {
      cpsFib(n - 2, (t1) => {
        f(t0 + t1);
      });
    })
  }
}

const num = 16;
console.time('cps');
const ans = cpsFib(num, (ans) => console.log(`fib(${num}): ${ans}`));
console.timeEnd('cps');
```

The problem is when I go over `16` as input it causes

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

But when I try it with `direct style` and with providing input more than `40`, it works very well

```
const num = 40;
const fib: (arg: number) => number = (n: number) => n <= 1 ? 1 : fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
console.log(`fib(${num}): ${fib(num)}`);
```

so I am trying to get a deep look on why `CPS` could not solve it with more than `16` while direct styling could.

As I get `CPS` opens stack in memory for each function passing and `direct style` opens stack in memory for each function invocation.

Comment: Your `fib` is odd, b/c it doesn't return anything. A function always returns a value. Besides you picked the wrong algorithm. Your `fib` uses an explicit fold, i.e. it starts with a final value and breaks it down into its smallest instances (0 and 1) and accumulates the result (using `+`). But `fib` requires the other way around. You need an unfold, i.e. start with a seed (the base case `0` in your example) and build your way up to the final value. Unfolding is much more efficient in connection with `fib`. You can google it for more information.

Comment: @IvenMarquardt
Arrow function in JS implicitly return if it has one statement, and for the algorithm yes I do know better ways to solve it, but I am just trying to compare `DS` to `CPS` with similar syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, direct style only stores `n` on the stack, whereas CPS style stores `n` and a lambda. I don't know precisely how typescript stores lambdas in memory, but at the very least it needs `t` and a function pointer, so each invocation takes at least 3 times the amount of stack space.

Much more significantly, each recursive step of your CPS solution also makes the stack deeper, due to the nesting, where the direct style goes down the stack for `f(n-1)`, then *back up* the stack, then down again for `f(n-2)`.

Usually for CPS to be stack safe, you have to implement trampolining or use a language implementation with tail call optimization.